# what's the meaning of $_ in helm template

Tags: go, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I want to know what's the meaning of $_ in helm template.

I konw helm template is using go sprig template:

[helm function_list](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/)

But where can I find go template grammar document?

Comment: It should not have any predefined value, but be `set` somewhere in in your template.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$_` is a [variable](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#hdr-Variables) with the name `_`.   The template grammar is described in the [package documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#pkg-overview).

Because `set` function returns a value, the following template action emits undesired data to the output.

```
 {{set $myDict "name4" "value4"}}
```

The examples in Helm documentation use assignment to `$_` to trap the output (assignments do not emit anything to the output).

```
 {{$_ := unset $myDict "name4"}}
```

A variable with any name can be used. The variable `$_` is used by convention to indicate that the value is not used. This is somewhat similar to the use of the [blank identifier](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Blank_identifier) in Go.